# BLE Scan crash on Android 12+

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-12

**THE PROBLEM**

Hi, I have encountered a problem that I am not able to solve on my own. I am an intern at Haia Consultancy, and I develop using Kotlin for Android run platforms. I am unable to perform a BLE scan on the S21+ android phone on Android 12, be it my code, or code from github. The application runs until I press the Scan button which performs a BLE Scan. The application crashes. This does not occur on lower versions of Android. It is very important that I am able to use android 12 targeted version in combination with Bluetooth Low Energy.

```
    2022-12-07 16:01:45.692 28797-28797 AndroidRuntime          
    com...e.ultrawidebandproofofconcept  E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.example.ultrawidebandproofofconcept, PID: 28797
        java.lang.SecurityException: Need android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN permission for AttributionSource { uid = 10366, packageName = com.example.ultrawidebandproofofconcept, attributionTag = null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@ff32c8f, next = null }: GattService registerScanner
            at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2438)
            at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2422)
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2405)
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2347)
            at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothGatt$Stub$Proxy.registerScanner(IBluetoothGatt.java:1886)
            at android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner$BleScanCallbackWrapper.startRegistration(BluetoothLeScanner.java:519)
            at android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner.startScan(BluetoothLeScanner.java:305)
            at android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner.startScan(BluetoothLeScanner.java:161)
            at com.example.ultrawidebandproofofconcept.MainActivity.startBleScan(MainActivity.kt:96)
            at com.example.ultrawidebandproofofconcept.MainActivity.onCreate$lambda-0(MainActivity.kt:80)
            at com.example.ultrawidebandproofofconcept.MainActivity.$r8$lambda$NQsLDkI5TsYB6INH-F0JwBK_SNM(Unknown Source:0)
            at com.example.ultrawidebandproofofconcept.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda2.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7792)
            at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:16112)
            at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1219)
            at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7769)
            at android.view.View.access$3800(View.java:910)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:30218)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8751)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
                                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
```

Guide ive followed:
https://punchthrough.com/android-ble-guide/

I have been following this guide until I came against the problem, at a certain point the webpage was updated notifying the reader that the guide is up to date with android 12+. I went to github repo of this guide and cloned the android12+ branch (https://github.com/PunchThrough/ble-starter-android/tree/feature/android-12-up). The same error occurred as In my project which is mentioned above. Me and my colleagues suspect that something is wrong with either my laptop or the phone provided by the company.
If targeted version is set to android 12+, the IDE suggests that you add an if statement to see if you the permissions are granted by the user:
[IDE's suggestion to see if the user has granted the permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mk1ua.png)
if I do not add the if statement generated by the IDE, and try to perform a BLE scan after ive asked for the user permissions, the application still crashes. Ive tried to print out the results into the console to see if the permissions are really granted.
I ask for the location permission from the user and I ask if the user is okay with me enabling the Bluetooth.
[printout permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C08jm.png)
[The results of the printout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9p5n.png)
As you can see I get a -1 as return when I check if the permissions are given for the Bluetooth scan. I assume this is an error code since you should only be getting either true(1) or false(0).

**ATTEMPTED SOLUTIONS**

I have tried to request not only the fine location permission but also the coarse location permission from the user, as that is the main difference between android 12 and down when it comes to Bluetooth low energy. However this did not make the difference. Since I don’t use Bluetooth for location related purposes, I explicitly stated that I will not be using location in the manifest file. This did not work either.
Does anyone know how to fix this? Can you run the projects referred in this document without the  issues? Does anyone know the leads? Any bit of information helps!

```
SOFTWARE & HARDWARE SPECIFICATIONS
Run on s21+ Android phone with Android 11
Project specifications:
targetSDK: 32
MinSDK: 31
Manifest permissions:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true"/>
```

The project Github Repository:
https://github.com/FedorTselishchev/UWB-POC-Stackoverflow

Please help, I want to see my family again.

**UPDATE 15/12/2022**
code bellow still crashes

```
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            requestPermissionLauncher.launch(
                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN
            )
            requestPermissionLauncher.launch(
                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
            )
            return
        }
        bleScanner.startScan(null, scanSettings, scanCallback)
```

Code bellow works, i dont understand how or why, but i am free man now.
Thank you kind strangerinos for assistance.

```
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            requestPermissionLauncher.launch(
                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN
            )
            requestPermissionLauncher.launch(
                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
            )
            return
        }
        bleScanner.startScan(null, scanSettings, scanCallback)
```

Comment: thanks for wall of text, but you forgot the stacktrace :)

Comment: ok, i just googled what that is, gimme a sec so i can generate one

Comment: ìve added the stacktrace sir.

Comment: great. now you should read it -> `java.lang.SecurityException: Need android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN permission` :)

Comment: great. now you should read it -> `java.lang.SecurityException: Need android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN permission` :)

Comment: But boss, thats the point. Ive done the permission requests before and it did not work. It does work on android <=11, but on android 12 it aint work. i even downloaded and run BLE scan projects from github that run on android 12+ and those also crashed on my device. So surely the problem is in the phone right? rright?

Comment: Please see if my answer solves your problem. Also dig in the docs I linked to

Answer (score 1):

It appears that Android 12 changes require your app to declare them in the manifest file:

> If your app targets Android 12 (API level 31) or higher, declare the following permissions in your app's manifest file:
>
> If your app looks for Bluetooth devices, such as BLE peripherals, declare the BLUETOOTH_SCAN permission.

Source: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/permissions

Answer (score 0):

Since your targetSdk is 32 and minimumSdk 31, you may need to declare only new Bluetooth permissions, as you don't need to derive user's location from scan results, no need to request location permissions. Declare the following permission in manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN"
        android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation"
        tools:targetApi="s" />
```

And request runtime user permissions as

```
requestMultiplePermissionLauncher.launch(arrayOf(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT))
```

This will launch permission request for Nearby devices.

If you target lower SDK versions or intend to derive user locations, only then declare and request for location permissions.

Follow this [link](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-app-permissions) for learning how to request runtime permissions.

Edit: if you intend to only scan for ble devices, not connect, then declare and request only scan permission, vomit connect permission.

You can also request permission using request code, follow this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#manage-request-code-yourself)

Comment: Hi, i really want to try out this solution but i have a problem. requestPermissionLauncher and the requestMultiplePermissionLauncher are not detected. i cannot import anything either. I suspect that i am missing a package that i need to add in the build.gradle file? if i google i dont get any reference for the package that i need to use. Ive even used the packages from the link that you have provided, but the project refuses to compile ;_;. What am i missing? What package do i need?

Comment: Have you added the dependencies mentioned in the linked Codelab?

Comment: Hi Varsha. I have fixed dependency issues in my project and was able to run the project & implement the permissions according the guide that you have provided. Now the application starts BLE Scan but still crashes. THe if statement that checks if the permission is given says that the permission is granted but still the crash occures with "Need android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT permission for AttributionSource " error. I am also unable to use the "requestMultiplePermissionLauncher.launch(arrayOf(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT))"

Comment: Do you have the code online anywhere? I could have a look.

Comment: Adding these 2 lines:

android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation"
tools:targetApi="s"

made a big difference between Android 12 and 13. After adding these, my app finally work on Android 13.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that when the if statement fires, only one request permission fires and not the other one. THe second time you get to the same function the if statement doesnt fire since the permission was given, but the second permission was not given and thus you still get the crash.